# No search results with act_as_ferret

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-ferret

I have this line on box model

```
   acts_as_ferret :fields => [ :model ]
```

of course, box table has a field named model.

this is the search action or the catalog controller

```
   def search
     @page_title = "Busqueda"
     if params[:commit] == "Search" || params[:q]
        @boxes = Box.find_with_ferret(params[:q].to_s.upcase)
     unless @boxes.size > 0
        flash.now[:notice] = "No boxess found matching your criteria"
end
```

and thats are  the search views ,this is _search_box.html.erb

```
    <%= form_tag({:action => "search"}, {:method => "get"} do ) %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q %>
    <%= submit_tag "Buscar" %>
    <% end %>
```

and this is search.html.erb

```
   <% render :partial => "search_box" %>
   <% if @boxes %>
   <p>Your search "<%= params[:q] %>" produced
   <%= pluralize @boxes.size, "result" %>:</p>
   <%= render(:partial => "boxes") %>
   <% end %>
```

Seems correct but the search always returns 0 results.

Comment: what are your logs saying? please have a look at this article for how to debug your rails applications http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: logs doesn't show anithing wrong i think.

Comment: your question lacks sufficient information to debugging it.

Comment: Solved it was tthe charset ,on database latin1 in teh application utf8